# IDEA IDE java class not found

Tags: java, class

I am student currently trying to make a game in java. However I can't seem to run the project with the IDEA IDE. I am getting the message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kamikaas.game.World" But when I look at the class structure I can't see why it wouldn't find the class. You can see the class structure and message here [image: IDEA screenshot]

Comment: do you have an import statement? seeing as we don't know anything of your project, we don't know what IDE you use, we don't know anything of your code, ...

Comment: turn it off and on again?

Comment: @Stultuske import statement wouldn't cause this, it wouldn't compile. IDE is mentioned - it's IDEA. I've inlined the screenshot

Comment: you don't have a main method, there is nothing to run

Comment: as @Stultuske points out, you'll need to add a main method to allow this to run - you can do this quickly in IDEA by typing `psvm` and hitting tab. However, that's still not your issue - the class file is not being built or is not being found when built - I believe that's what the red X in the run config means. Do you have it configured to make on run?

Comment: @Stultuske true enough, but then Java complains about a missing main method, not about a missing class. This probably has to do with auto-compile being off, or some other force that is preventing the project from building properly.

Comment: What happens when you hover over the grey underlined word `World` in your source? Does IDEA tell you anything useful? Can you add a screenshot of your `Run`->`Edit configurations` screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably an entry point issue. Make sure you set the entry point to your main class (the class with main method).

After you edit: As I guessed, your World class doesn't have a *main* method. You have to start your project with the correct class.

Comment: It's not reporting a missing `main` method - it can't find the class. Granted, once it finds the class, your answer will be relevant, but there's another problem before the OP gets there

Comment: No I think this is an entry point issue, it happened to me a lot.

Comment: If that was the problem, the error would say `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kaimkaas.game.World.main([Ljava.lang.String;)` - try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got a working project now, I added Maven to my project and it fixed my problem. As for the entry point suggestion, I have looked numerous times and it was correct. I don't know what the cause was but I don't care if it doesn't exist anymore.